# Windows Store App : How to launch an other app?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

How to launch any other app from a windows store app ? Is this possible : I can't find ANY MENTION anywhere searching google.

Comment: Which app you want to launch ? The app which is having [protocol activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779670.aspx), can only be launched from other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Xyroid in the comment, protocol activation is your only option. He already mentioned the documentation.

A colleague of mine wrote a blogpost about using protocol activation to do some actions with Skype: http://vdcruijsen.net/2013/04/launching-skype-from-your-own-windows-store-app/

Hopefully this will give you some points to get started.